# Automatically converting GeoPackages to ZIP archives with Shapefiles and QML/SLD with native QGIS

Tags: qgis

Currently we use a third party tool (mygeodata website) to convert our geopackage back to a zip folder **with all the contents of the geopackage and the styles intact (even the standard Style Setting). But we want this to do purely in QGIS and not just a simple export but all of the geopackage being exported at once. Is this possible?**

Comment: Why do you say "spliting" (splitting?) in the question title? What's being split here? From the rest of the question it seems you want to create a zip file from a Geodatabase, and if a Geodatabase is a folder containing everything you need to zip then you can use Python modules to do that, either from the QGIS Python command line or you'll have to write a function or plugin.

Comment: What is being split here is the Geodatabase, maybe I should have refered it better. Everything from the gdb file is extracted and put into a zip file. Including the styles that were set to standard. Gonna rededit the question later.

Comment: So you're converting the datasets, then? What is the expected output format inside of the zIp file? Just another FGDB, or shapefiles? Something else?

Comment: Shapefiles and the QML/SLD files for the style/form of the attribute tables and forms.

Comment: I have updated my question i had used too much wrong terminology.

Comment: Why don't you just export the Geopackage into a Shapefile and save the style file?

Comment: Because there are just too many shapefiles to handle, doing at one by one takes too much time. So we need to have a process/script do it all at once. This geopackage is created by  a QGIS model, by packing all the layers of that QGIS model including style load as geopackage. This just has to with the fact to make we just have one filepath to set and the styles are set to default. However for our client it is more interesting to have a zip file with the shapefiles and QML files.

Comment: Then the easiest way I could think of is writing a Python Script to accomplish it. I don't have a specific solution though.

Comment: Any tips and tricks like for say a reference book or code template to start from?

Comment: PyQGIS Cookbook: https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/index.html